# What is wrong with this _init_

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is wrong with this python code? I have been trying to learn how to use `_init_` but can't get it to work

```
class Giraffes:
    def _init_(self, spots):
        self.giraffe_spots = spots

ozwald = Giraffes(100)
print(ozwald.giraffe_spots)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **two** underscores before and after:

```
def __init__(self, spots):
```

You only used one on either side. When incorrectly spelled, it won't be called when creating a new instance.

Demo:

```
>>> class Giraffes:
...     def __init__(self, spots):
...         self.giraffe_spots = spots
... 
>>> ozwald = Giraffes(100)
>>> print(ozwald.giraffe_spots)
100
```

Comment: Give us mobile users a break :(

Comment: @Haidro: only if you do the same for me when I am mobile. :-P