# Question regarding creating Classes & Objects

Tags: python, oop

I saw a code that doesn't work in my Visual Studio Code. Do I need to download another extension of Python or do normal Python work?

[image]

```
class Bank:
   def _init_(self):
      self.balance = 1000
   def get_balance(self):
      return self.balance
   def withdraw(self, amount):
      self.balance = self.balance - amount
      return amount
        
my_bank = Bank()
my_bank.withdraw(100)
balance = my_bank.get_balance()
print(balance)
my_bank.withdraw(50)
balance = my_bank.get_balance()
print(balance)
```

Comment: try *def __init__(self)* - Note two underscores either side of *init*

Comment: no you don't need additional packages. but since you are writing a script, you need to have `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310721/what-is-wrong-with-this-init, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61312130/problems-with-init?noredirect=1 and others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class is not initializing the balance variable because; `_init_` in a class should be written with two underscores, not one.

```
class Bank:
   def __init__(self):
      self.balance = 1000
```

Comment: I see, thank you so much for correcting and solving my issues!